# IRF3205 switching problem

Tags: mosfet, switching, powermosfet

I bought a power mosfet(IRF3205) and tried to switch but mosfet is not behaving as I expected when gate pin is triggered it doesnt change its position.

Below is how my schematic looks like, I could not find problem.
Any help is appreciated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLGB6z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Does the LED remain on or off?

Comment: It remains on I cant change it

Comment: Then you possibly have source and drain swapped over OR you have destroyed the gate-source region with static electricity.

Comment: what is the amplitude of your gate voltage

Comment: Is the CLK1 ground reference connected to V1 ground?

Comment: @Navaro Amplitude is 5V ,I have also tried with IRF4405 same problem occured

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes All circuit is grounded together

Comment: If you connect the gate to ground, does the LED turn off?

Comment: can you explain if the LED stays on or off? And are you sure R2 = 1kohm and not 100kohm for example

Comment: I should have clarified a few things, I builted circuit like you see above ,while  I give 5V to the gate led turned "ON" but after I left gate source idle (not grounded) led stayed "ON" am I doing something wrong?

Comment: in that case make sure your gate is somewhat grounded by adding a pull-down resistor of 1k from gate to ground. See if that helps and please edit your questions. to be clear looking from your source to the gate , the 100 ohm and 1k make a voltage divider.